# Exercise 30 from Chapter 1 ("Measure Theory") of Stein and Shakarchi's "Real Analysis"

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the following exercise from [1] (p. 44):

> ***30*** If $E$ and $F$ are measurable, and $m(E) > 0$, $M(F) > 0$, prove that
>   $$
> E + F = \{x + y : x \in E, x \in F\}
> $$
>   contains an interval.

If $E = F$, this exercise reduces to exercise 29 (see below), which I am able to prove according to the hint. But I cant figure out how to modify exercise 29's proof to prove exercise 30's more general claim. Any help will be appreciated.

> ***29*** Suppose $E$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $m(E) > 0$. Prove that the difference set of $E$, which is defined by
>   $$
> \{z \in \mathbb{R} : z = x - y \mbox{ for some } x, y \in E\}
> $$
>   contains an open interval centered at the origin.
>
> If $E$ contains an interval, then the conclusion is straightforward. In general, one may rely on Exercise 28.
>
> [Hint: Indeed, by Exercise 28, there exists an open interval $I$ so that $m(E \cap I) \geq (9/10)m(I)$. If we denote $E \cap I$ by $E_0$, and suppose that the difference set of $E_0$ does not contain an open interval around the origin, then for arbitrarily small $a$ the sets $E_0$ and $E_0 + a$ are disjoint. From the fact that $(E_0 \cup (E_0 + a)) \subseteq (I \cup (I + a))$ we get a contradiction, since the lift-hand side has measure $2m(E_0)$, while the right-hand side has measure only slightly larger than $m(I)$.]

For completeness, here's exercise 28 mentioned in exercise 29:

> ***28*** Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $m_*(E) > 0$. Prove that for each $0 < \alpha < 1$, there exists an open interval $I$ so that
>   $$
> m_*(E\cap I) \geq \alpha m_*(I).
> $$
>   Loosely speaking, this estimate shows that $E$ contains almost a whole interval.
>
> [Hint: Choose an open set $\mathcal{O}$ that contains $E$, and such that $m_*(E) \geq \alpha m_*(\mathcal{O})$. Write $\mathcal{O}$ as the countable union of disjoint open intervals, and show that one of these intervals must satisfy the desired property.]

---

***References***

[1] Stein, Elias M. and Shakarchi, Rami. Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces. Princeton University Press (2005)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also don't know how to deduce Exercise 30 from the proof of Exercise 29 which you have shown, but I know a direct proof of Exercise 30 (I don't recall where I learned it).

Assume wlog. that $m(E)<\infty$, $m(F)<\infty$ (otherwise work with subsets of finite measure). Consider

$$\mathbf{1}_E*\mathbf{1}_F(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{E}(x-y)\mathbf{1}_F(y)dy$$

and notice that if $\mathbf{1}_E*\mathbf{1}_F(x)>0$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then this implies $x\in E+F$ (even more: the set of $y$ such that $x-y\in E$ and $y\in F$ must have positive measure). Therefore we have

$$A:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,:\,\mathbf{1}_E*\mathbf{1}_F(x)>0\}\subset E+F$$

The point is now that $\mathbf{1}_E*\mathbf{1}_F$ is a continuous function (see comment).

Thus the set $A$ is open. Also, $m(A)>0$ since by Fubini we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_E*\mathbf{1}_F(x) dx = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_E(x) dx\right) \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{F}(y) dy\right)= m(E)m(F)>0$$

So $A$ and therefore also $E+F$ contains an open interval.

Comment: Nice solution. One minor point: I don't think that continuity of the convolution follows immediately from dominated convergence. But one can show (using the density of $C_c$) that the translation $x \mapsto f(\cdot - x)$ is continuous from $\Bbb{R} \to L^p$ for $f \in L^p$ and $1\leq p < \infty$. For $p=2$ this implies the desired continuity together with continuity of the $L^2$ scalar product.

Comment: @PhoemueX: You're right, dominated convergence cannot be applied. Thanks!